# Using css, can I combine pattern gradient (4px by 4px) and transparent gradient (all over the page)

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I'm trying to overlay 2 different gradients, without using any image:

- one repeatable gradient (6px by 6px) that makes an hash-like image.
- one vertically transparent gradient all over the page (100% to 0%).

Here is the code I tried unsuccefully:

```
html{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

body{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #C6C6C6 0%, #C6C6C6 25%, #FFFFFF 25%, #FFFFFF 50%, #C6C6C6 50%, #C6C6C6 75%, #FFFFFF 75%, #FFFFFF 100%);
    background-size: 6px 6px;
}
```

Any idea is this is possible ?

Comment: Given that you've only included `-moz-linear-gradient`, you're only looking for Gecko-based browser support?

Comment: You would have to comma separate the gradients in a single background-image declaration on the body...ditto with the other properties.